# how to automatically name lambda functors which inside work thread pool

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-asio

I am trying to push a bunch of lambda expressions on a thread pool in C++.
i'm using boost::basic_thread_pool which take care of one's work(lambda functor) sequentially and schedule in work queue.

When I put the work in the worker_thread_pool, lambda function is put in and lambda function has no name, so I can't log the lambda function even if I want to. When I put the lambda function, I ask if there is a way to enable logging.

```
thread_pool tp{4};

tp.submit([]() {sleep(4);}); // i wants to log some issue If it takes more than a second. but no information about lambda expression
```

Can anyone tell me any idea if this is possible?

thanks

Comment: Do you mean like `auto lambda = []() {sleep(4);}; tp.submit(std::move(lambda));` ?

Comment: If the return value isn't being used, you could have the lambda return its name: `tp.submit([]{sleep(4); return "sleepytime";};`

Comment: ¿Which name should be assigned to lambda here, by what logic, and when you are going to actually use it? ¿Why don't you assign required names manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no submit member function on `asio::thread_pool`.

Also, naming tasks is not a responsibility of the pool. Post tasks with names, if you need.

Perhaps you are using a logging framework that can detect function names from compiler-defined macros, like Boost Log:

```
void Hibernation() {
    BOOST_LOG_FUNCTION();
    LOG() << "Start";
    sleep(4);
    LOG() << "Exit";
}
```

That won't work with lambdas, because one succinct definition of a lambda¹ is  as an unnamed function. But you can add a wrapper that adds the scope name, again using Boost Log for the example:

```
template <size_t N, typename F> auto named(char const (&n)[N], F&& f) {
    return [&n, f = std::forward<F>(f)](auto&&... args) mutable -> decltype(auto) {
        BOOST_LOG_NAMED_SCOPE(n);
        std::move(f)(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
    };
}
```

> **Note** how `BOOST_LOG_NAMED_SCOPE` is used with an explicit name instead of `BOOST_LOG_FUNCTION`. See the documentation: [*the user can replace the problematic BOOST_LOG_FUNCTION usage with the BOOST_LOG_NAMED_SCOPE macro and explicitly write the desired scope name*](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/detailed/expressions.html#log.detailed.expressions.formatters.named_scope:%7E:text=the%20user%20can%20replace%20the%20problematic%20BOOST_LOG_FUNCTION%20usage%20with%20the%20BOOST_LOG_NAMED_SCOPE%20macro%20and%20explicitly%20write%20the%20desired%20scope%20name)

### Full Demo

```cpp
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/log/attributes/named_scope.hpp>
#include <boost/log/expressions.hpp>
#include <boost/log/trivial.hpp>
#include <boost/log/utility/setup/console.hpp>

auto& s_log = []() -> auto& {
    using namespace boost::log;
    add_console_log(std::cout,
                    keywords::format = expressions::stream
                        << "[" << expressions::format_named_scope("Scope", keywords::format = "%F:%l:%c")
                        << "] " << expressions::message);
    auto core = core::get();
    core->add_global_attribute("Scope", attributes::named_scope());
    static trivial::logger_type instance;
    return instance;
}();
#define LOG() BOOST_LOG(s_log)

template <size_t N, typename F> auto named(char const (&n)[N], F&& f) {
    return [&n, f = std::forward<F>(f)](auto&&... args) mutable -> decltype(auto) {
        BOOST_LOG_NAMED_SCOPE(n);
        std::move(f)(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
    };
}

void Hibernation() {
    BOOST_LOG_FUNCTION();
    LOG() << "Start";
    sleep(4);
    LOG() << "Exit";
}

int main() {
    BOOST_LOG_FUNCTION();
    LOG() << "Hello world";

    boost::asio::thread_pool tp{4};

    post(tp, Hibernation);

    auto task = []() {
        LOG() << "Start";
        sleep(1);
        LOG() << "Exit";
    };

    sleep(1);
    post(tp, task); // naked lamda, no thread scope at all

    sleep(1);
    post(tp, named("SleepingBeauty", task)); // named

    tp.join();
    LOG() << "Bye";
}
```

Showing:

```
[test.cpp:35:main] Hello world
[test.cpp:28:Hibernation] Start
[] Start
[test.cpp:22:SleepingBeauty] Start
[] Exit
[test.cpp:22:SleepingBeauty] Exit
[test.cpp:28:Hibernation] Exit
[test.cpp:35:main] Bye
```

[image]

### BONUS

I'd suggest not (ab)using `asio::thread_pool` for your own task-oriented work queuing, removing the complaint that it lacks features. However, just to humor the idea, here's how you can add proper thread names to the pool's threads as well:

```cpp
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/log/attributes/named_scope.hpp>
#include <boost/log/expressions.hpp>
#include <boost/log/trivial.hpp>
#include <boost/log/utility/setup/console.hpp>
#include <deque>

auto& s_log = []() -> auto& {
    using namespace boost::log;
    add_console_log(std::cout,
                    keywords::format = expressions::stream
                        << "[" << expressions::format_named_scope("Scope", keywords::format = "%c")
                        << "] " << expressions::message);
    auto core = core::get();
    core->add_global_attribute("Scope", attributes::named_scope());
    static trivial::logger_type instance;
    return  instance;
}();
#define LOG() BOOST_LOG(s_log)

template <size_t N, typename F> auto named(char const (&n)[N], F&& f) {
    return [&n, f = std::forward<F>(f)](auto&&... args) mutable -> decltype(auto) {
        BOOST_LOG_NAMED_SCOPE(n);
        std::move(f)(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
    };
}

void Hibernation() {
    BOOST_LOG_FUNCTION();
    LOG() << "Start";
    sleep(4);
    LOG() << "Exit";
}

static void Worker(char const (&name)[3], boost::asio::thread_pool& pool) {
    BOOST_LOG_FUNCTION();
    BOOST_LOG_NAMED_SCOPE(name);
    pool.attach();
}

int main() {
    BOOST_LOG_FUNCTION();
    LOG() << "Hello world";

    boost::asio::thread_pool tp{0};
    std::deque<std::thread> workers;
    workers.emplace_back(Worker, std::ref("#1"), ref(tp));
    workers.emplace_back(Worker, std::ref("#2"), ref(tp));
    workers.emplace_back(Worker, std::ref("#3"), ref(tp));
    workers.emplace_back(Worker, std::ref("#4"), ref(tp));

    post(tp, Hibernation);

    auto task = [] { LOG() << "Start"; sleep(1); LOG() << "Exit"; };

    sleep(1);
    post(tp, task); // naked lamda, no thread scope at all

    sleep(1);
    post(tp, named("SleepingBeauty", task)); // named

    tp.join();
    for (auto& w: workers)
        if (w.joinable())
            w.join();
    LOG() << "Bye";
}
```

With the output

```
[main] Hello world
[Worker->#3->Hibernation] Start
[Worker->#2] Start
[Worker->#4->SleepingBeauty] Start
[Worker->#2] Exit
[Worker->#4->SleepingBeauty] Exit
[Worker->#3->Hibernation] Exit
[main] Bye
```

[image]

> *Mind you, seeing how clunky that becomes, we've definitely crossed the threshold for "abusing `asio::thread_pool`" in my opinion.*

---

¹ glossing over the closure-semantics (captures)

Comment: Thanks @sehe for detailed answer

however As we saw in your first example, when you run line code 52(post(tp, named("SleepingBeauty", task)); // named), the console says [test.cpp:22:Sleeping Beauty], but I want line 52 to be output. 

I ask if there is a solution to this.

Comment: That's weird. Line numbers were never in the question at all. Just remove them from the formatter?